# use react() from DM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to use .react() from DM way. But the reaction into the post is sended by bot. I need send a reaction by the user.

```js
var guild = bot.guilds.get(GUILD_ID);
   
if(guild && guild.channels.get(ch_ID)){
        
   guild.channels.get(ch_ID).fetchMessage(msg_ID).then(message => {
       message.react('')
   })
}
```

Comment: A client cannot add a reaction as another user. Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I shared in a comment...

> A client cannot add a reaction as another user.

Unfortunately, that means that you can't accomplish what you're trying to do within the Discord API. You can *read* reactions, but the bot simply would never be able to force someone to add a reaction.